# how to display images from a datasbase on to a different page

Tags: php, database

So I have this code that stores images into a database and retrieves them. The pictures currently display on the profiletest.php page under the form where you submit a photo. Instead i would like these images to display on the exploretest.php page. How would i go about doing this.

**profiletest.php**

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
       if (getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])== FALSE)
       {
           echo "Please select an image.";
       }
       else
       {
           $name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
           $image= base64_encode(file_get_contents(addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])));
           saveimage($name,$image);
       }
   }

   function saveimage($name, $image)
   {
       $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","loginsystem"); 

       $sql="insert into testimage(name,image) values('$name', '$image')";
       $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
       if ($query)
       {
           echo "<br/>Image Uploaded.";
       }
       else
       {
           echo "<br/>Image not uploaded";
       }
   }
    display();

     function display(){
       $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","loginsystem");
        $sql="select * from testimage";
         $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         $num=mysqli_num_rows($query);
         for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
             $result=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
             $img=$result['image'];
             echo '<img  class="exploreimg" src="data:image;base64, '.$img.'" style="max-height:300px;max-width:300px; margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-top:30px;">';


         }
     }

?>
```

Comment: Change the file name?

Comment: I have a profile page that only allows users to upload a photo through the form thats on profiletest.php. Thats where the script is for images to go into the database. Instead of them displaying on the profiletest.php page. I need the photos to display on the exploretest.php page

Comment: Please mention what you tried in exploretest.php. The display function, if copy-pasted in exploretest.php should work well. If you want the function to be modular, put that in a third php file and call it by 'include' in exploretest.php

Comment: Didn't realise the display function had to go in exploretest.php. Works fine now thanks